# symfony doctrine admin generator sort by virtual columns

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm working with the Symfony doctrine admin generator.

I've added a couple of virtual columns as detailed on this page http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12

What I want to be able to do is sort my list based on those virtual columns.

http://redotheweb.com/2008/09/25/sorting-by-custom-column-in-the-symfony-admin-generator/

That is how to do it with the Propel plugin but that details the use of a "sort_method" configuration in the yaml generator file, no such configuration item exists for the Doctrine admin generator.

Just wonder if there is something I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023247/how-to-sort-own-columns-in-admin-panel-with-symfony

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to use this plugin:

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/DbFinderPlugin

It's this plugin that gives the "sort_method" configuration ability.

Hmmm, seems like a lot of work for something as simple as sorting by a different column.