# Symfony Admin generator: sort on non existing field(in partial)

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, admin-generator

in an admin generator created module I added a fictif field using a partial.
but apparentely the "sort" link (exists on every field name to set the sorting)
can I make symfony show a link for sorting on this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In symfony, it's a lot of pain for such an apparently easy thing. I haven't tested any way, but I can point you to some promising resources.

Look at this topic:

[symfony doctrine admin generator sort by virtual columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899628/symfony-doctrine-admin-generator-sort-by-virtual-columns)

User uses [DbFinderPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/DbFinderPlugin).

Here you have a tutorial that [tell how to achieve this in another way](http://www.seattleveggieburgers.com/blog/?p=120), and [another tutorial](http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2011/01/08/symfony-1-4-admin-generator-sort-on-custom-column/).